# Как нормализовать выборку для задачи классификации?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy

Прохожу курс на coursera.

Для выполнения задания нужно нормализовать выборку для задачи классификации, из двух признаков и одной целевой переменной.
Когда я просто загружаю выборку:

```
# Тестовая - аналогично
x_train = train_data.iloc[:,1:].values
y_train = train_data.iloc[:, 0].values
```

И дохожу до следующего кода:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
y_train_scaled = scaler.transform(y_train)
```

ловлю исключение:

```
X -= self.mean_
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (300,) (2,) (300,)
```

Также выводится предупреждение:

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and
will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using 
X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) 
if it contains a single sample.
```

Но `reshape(1, -1)` превращает мой вектор признаков с shape `(300, 2)` в вектор с shape `(1, 600)`.

Останется ли задача после таких преобразований задачей классификации?(Судя по исключению, советующему использовать метод оценки для линейной регрессии - нет)

Каким образом я могу нормализовать признаки для этой задачи?

Спасибо!

Comment: reshape - изменяет размерность массива, но не изменяет сами данные. [Нормализация данных](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics)) (или признаков) - приведение их к одному и тому же масштабу. Например, возраст и зарплата - возраст от 0 до 100, зарплата от 0 до <много> - нормализованные занчения будут лежать в пределах [0; 1]. Что вы, собственно, хотите сделать - изменить размерность массива или нормализовать признаки? Операции друг с другом никак не связаны - нормализованные данные будут иметь ту же самую размерность.

Comment: @m9_psy Это так. Но для того, чтобы нормализовать выборку с помощью sklearn, следуя предупреждению, нужно сделать reshape вектора, создав из 300 объектов с двумя признаками 600 объектов с одним. Меня именно это смущает. Также там требуется подавать одинаковые векторы, а в целевом векторе только 300 значений - по одному на объект, и как получить из них 600 - тоже непонятно. В любом случае спасибо.

Comment: Очень трудно помочь вам не имея возможности воспроизвести ошибку/проблему. Приведите небольшой пример входных данных. `Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated` - это ругается на `y_train`, а не на `x_train`, соответственно преобразовывать надо `y_train`...

Comment: @MaxU [Вот](http://dropmefiles.com/dC5Vw), ссылка будет действительна в течение 7 дней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем CSV файл в Pandas DataFrame

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\perceptron-train.csv')

x_train = df.iloc[:,1:]
y_train = df.iloc[:,0]
```

Воспользуемся StandardScaler

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
```

тренируем модель

```
scaler.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

воспользуемся "натренированной" моделью - обычно здесь мы подставляем новые данные (test data set), которые надо прогнать через модель:

```
In [34]: scaler.transform(x_train)
Out[34]:
array([[  4.86706474e-03,   1.33499892e+00],
       [ -9.43323370e-01,   1.23821147e+00],
       [  3.41902020e-01,  -1.46859294e+00],
       [  2.08121089e-01,   3.35813367e-01],
       [ -1.22624550e+00,  -7.32950072e-01],
       [  2.77953452e-01,   3.52700093e-02],
       [ -1.83075769e+00,  -2.52158659e-01],
       [  4.96641810e-02,   2.26227468e-02],
       [  9.48021963e-02,  -3.55349782e-01],
       [ -6.06032097e-01,  -3.38575608e-01],
       [  9.79935538e-01,  -1.02816205e+00],
       [ -7.01817586e-01,   7.10992037e-01],
       [ -1.21940824e+00,   1.01676970e+00],
       [  3.11425812e-01,   7.60370075e-01],
       [ -1.13031225e-01,   1.40955091e-01],
       [ -3.27605081e-01,  -2.34727633e-01],
       ...
```

Comment: Мне StandardScaler нужен именно для нормализации. В задании обучается sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron. Проблема основная в том, что scaler.transform() требует reshape делать, если количество фич не совпадает с количеством целевых переменных(300x2 vs 300 в моем случае), и тогда разрушается выборка - получается, что 300 объектов с двумя признаками превращаются в 600 с одним.

Comment: @justpainm8, тогда я не понимаю в чем заключается вопрос - `x_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)` дает вам нормализованный "data set" - просто работайте с ним и всё. `y_train` - нормализовать не надо...

Comment: Я так пробовал, но это не верно - ответ не сходится. Да и не должны ребята из вшэ [врать](http://i.imgur.com/onGSXfh.png)

Comment: @justpainm8, в вашей ссылке - все правильно. Сначала тренируется модель (находятся параметры) на "train data set", потом преобразовывется "test data set" с использованием данной модели. В обоих случаях число "features" (столбцов) совпадает...

Comment: Да, спасибо вам большое. Меня чего-то переклинило из-за моих обозначений. Теперь разобрался.